# Duplicated sheets in excel file with if_sheet_exists='replace'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I use the following code to write dataframes from a dictionary to excel sheet. The sheet name is the key from dictionary. The code also checks for the presence of the file (in case of missing file, create one) and replaces old sheet with new data from previous runs.

```
df_dict = {}
data = [[0.1,3,0.4], [0.2,6,0.9], [0.3,8,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['c', 's', 'e'])
df_dict['AA'] = df
data = [[0.1,2,0.3], [0.2,6,0.4], [0.3,9,0.6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['c', 's', 'e'])
df_dict['BB'] = df

print(df_dict)
excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
if not os.path.isfile(excel_file):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    wb.save(filename=excel_file)

for key in df_dict:
    df = df_dict[key]
    with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:  
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key)
```

However, by running the code, multiple times, I see duplicated sheets. For example, I see AA,BB,AA1,BB1, and so on. How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add engine = 'openpyxl' inside pd.ExcelWriter

```
 for key in df_dict:
     df = df_dict[key]
     with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:  
         df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key)
```

Comment: Same result. It doesn't work.